# A question about convex functions of minimum and maximum

Tags: real-analysis, convex-optimization

A question about convex functions of minimum and maximum

Let $f_1, f_2$ are two convex functions $\mathbb{R^n}\to \mathbb{R}$

then I prove that their $\max\{f_1(x),f_2(x),\forall x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ is convex

Is their minimum is also convex?

Answer (score 2):

$f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=-x$ gives a counterexample.

Comment: Sir..Do you mean $$\min\{f,g\}=\frac{f+g-\vert f-g \vert }{2}=\frac{- \vert 2x \vert}{2}$$ is not convex?

Comment: @ChinnapparajR If you draw the lines $y=x$ and $y=-x$ you can see immediately that $\min \{f,g\}$ is not convex.

Comment: Ok sir. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

take $f_1(x)=x^2$ and $f_2(x)=x^2+7$

then $ f(x)=\min \{f_1(x),f_2(x)\}$ is not convex function